# jquery images with equal height

Tags: jquery, image, height, equals, pageload

I am trying to write a Jquery function which will match the heights of all images on a page with the same class name.

This works as expected providing the internet connection is decent. If the images take a while to load, then it fails to display any images. I assume the function is determining the image to be 0px height and setting this to all.

How can I get around this?

Many thanks

```
function equalizeClass(className) {
    var equaliserHeight = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var i = 0;
    $('.'+className).each(function() {
        $(this).imagesLoaded(function() {
            i++;
            height = $(this).height();
            if(height>equaliserHeight) {
                equaliserHeight = height;
            }   
        });
    });
    $('.'+className).css("height", equaliserHeight);
}

$(function() {
equalizeClass('products-page-product-img'); // Equalize product list thumbnails
});
```

Comment: The clue would be you might need to check once all the images are loaded, then you need to do the equalisation.

Comment: I have added imagesLoaded() plugin from desandro.com which seamed to be what I need. But now the images won't show at all and I get the following error in my console. Is this clashing with my bootstrap maybe? - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: Can you show the snippet with the plugin, please?

Comment: you can try imagesloaded library, so you know when an image is loaded and take action -- http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: @Tasos Did you even see what Thomas said in his previous comment?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar -- now i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wait to page load.
Replace:

```
$(function() {
  equalizeClass('products-page-product-img');
});
```

with:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  equalizeClass('products-page-product-img');
});
```